# Using a checkbox to change an existing database value

Tags: asp.net

I currently have a checkbox that remains checked or unchecked based on the value in the database.  I want the checkbox to be able to change dynamically, so that if it's checked upon loading the page and I change it to unchecked, it will change the database value as well as redirect to a different page.  Right now I am unable to change the database value and redirect to a different page.  I have autopost back set to true currently.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=184.168.47.21;Initial Catalog=RecruitPursuit;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=RecruitPursuit;Password=Recruit20!8"))
    using (SqlCommand dataCommand =
            new SqlCommand("select SportHasPositions from Sport Where Sport_Id = @Sport_Id", dataConnection))

    {
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@Sport_Id";
        param2.Value = Session["SportID"];
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add(param2);

        dataConnection.Open();
        sportHasPositions = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }

    if (sportHasPositions == "No")
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = true;
        Panel1.Visible = false;
    }

    if (sportHasPositions == "Yes")
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = false;
        Panel1.Visible = true;
    }

}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
    {
        String conString = @"Data Source=184.168.47.21;Initial Catalog=RecruitPursuit;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=RecruitPursuit;Password=Recruit20!8";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        //create a command behavior object
        String cmdString = "UPDATE Sport SET SportHasPositions = @SportHasPositions WHERE Sport_Id = @Sport_Id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);

        SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter();
        param0.ParameterName = "@SportHasPositions";
        param0.Value = "Yes";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param0);

        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@Sport_Id";
        param1.Value = Session["SportID"];
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        int added = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            // Output.Text = err.Message;
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        Response.Redirect("Pick Positions.aspx");
    }
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            String conString = @"Data Source=184.168.47.21;Initial Catalog=RecruitPursuit;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=RecruitPursuit;Password=Recruit20!8";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

            //create a command behavior object
            String cmdString = "UPDATE Sport SET SportHasPositions = @SportHasPositions WHERE Sport_Id = @Sport_Id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);

            SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter();
            param0.ParameterName = "@SportHasPositions";
            param0.Value = "No";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param0);

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@Sport_Id";
            param1.Value = Session["SportID"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            int added = 0;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                // Output.Text = err.Message;
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }

}
```

Comment: is the checkbox hitting the CheckBox1_CheckedChanged when you check it? Are you getting an error? Please add more detail as to what is happening so I can help you

Comment: No errors.  And it's hitting Checkbox1_CheckChanged, but it's not executing the way I need it.  If its unchecked on loading and then it's checked, the panel is hidden an the value is changed in the database.  If it's checked on loading and then it is unchecked, the user is redirected to a new page and the value is changed in the database

Comment: It looks like since you are changing the checkbox on page load, it then calls the checkedChanged method causing it to change again and then Redirect you to the page. Is that what is happening? And you just want it to be initially set on page load and then have the user change it causing the checkedChanged method to be called?

Comment: Yes.  I just ran it again and if the button is checked on page load, I'm unable to uncheck it with the checkChanged method.  If it's unchecked, and I check it automatically redirects me to the page.  I need it to be able to uncheck it and be redirected to the page and check it and hide the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [asp.net life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) runs the `Page_Load` event before the `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` event. Since in your `Page_Load`, you are setting the checkbox, even if the user changed it, the `Page_Load` changes it back before the `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` can change it in the database. To fix this you can use the [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)
 flag so the `Page_Load` only sets the Checkbox on the initial page load.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=184.168.47.21;Initial Catalog=RecruitPursuit;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=RecruitPursuit;Password=Recruit20!8"))
        using (SqlCommand dataCommand =
                new SqlCommand("select SportHasPositions from Sport Where Sport_Id = @Sport_Id", dataConnection))

        {
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@Sport_Id";
            param2.Value = Session["SportID"];
            dataCommand.Parameters.Add(param2);

            dataConnection.Open();
            sportHasPositions = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }

        if (sportHasPositions == "No")
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        if (sportHasPositions == "Yes")
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = false;
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Anytime! If you would, please mark this as the answer so anyone coming to this thread can see how it was resolved. Thanks.